# Breadth-First into Uniform Cost LISP

Tags: lisp, artificial-intelligence, common-lisp

I am a beginner in LISP and I'm working on an exercise that requires me to make modifications to a breath-first search in order to convert it to a uniform-cost search.

Needless to say, I am extremely confused. I understand the basics of how breadth-first search and how uniform-cost search work, but I am having trouble implementing it.

I have some code for breadth-first search as well as the structure of nodes and expansion methods below, but I am having trouble in developing the uniform-cost search.

I understand it is supposed to take the lowest cost path, but I am not sure how to implement it all. I don't quite understand how it is supposed to save all those paths and edges while working through the entire map (the map of which I'm working with is the Romania Road Map, I'm sure google will bring up a copy)

Anyways the code I have so far is below:

```
;The Problem: 
setq ex2 '(
             (Arad           ( (Zerind 75) (Sibiu 140) (Timisoara 118)                   ) )
             (Oradea         ( (Zerind 71) (Sibiu 151)                                   ) )
             (Zerind         ( (Oradea 71) (Arad 75)                                     ) )
             (Timisoara      ( (Lugoj 111) (Arad 118)                                    ) )
             (Lugoj          ( (Timisoara 111) (Medhadia 70)                             ) )
             (Mehadia        ( (Lugoj 70) (Drobeta 75)                                   ) )
             (Drobeta        ( (Mehadia 75) (Craiova 120)                                ) )
             (Sibiu          ( (Oradea 151) (Arad 140) (Rimnicu-Vilcea 80) (Fagaras 99)  ) )
             (Rimnicu-Vilcea ( (Sibiu 80) (Craiova 146) (Pitesti 97)                     ) )
             (Craiova        ( (Rimnicu-Vilcea 146) (Drobeta 120) (Pitesti 138)          ) )
             (Fagaras        ( (Sibiu 99) (Bucharest 211)                                ) )
             (Pitesti        ( (Rimnicu-Vilcea 97) (Craiova 138) (Bucharest 101)         ) )
             (Bucharest      ( (Fagaras 211) (Pitesti 101) (Giurgiu 90) (Urziceni 85)    ) )
             (Giurgiu        ( (Bucharest 90)                                            ) )
             (Neami          ( (Iasi 87)                                                 ) )
             (Iasi           ( (Neami 87) (Vasiui 92)                                    ) )
             (Vasiui         ( (Iasi 92) (Urziceni 142)                                  ) )
             (Urziceni       ( (Bucharest 85) (Hirsova 98) (Vasiui 142)                  ) )
             (Hirsova        ( (Urziceni 98) (Eforie 86)                                 ) )
             (Eforie         ( (Hirsova 86)                                              ) )
) )

(setq problem3 (list 'Arad 'Bucharest ex2))

 ;return the start state from a problem
(defun initial-state (problem)
   (car problem))

; return the goal state from a problem
(defun goal-state (problem)
   (cadr problem))

; return the successor list from a problem
(defun adj-list (problem)
   (caddr problem))

; construct a node from a state and a parent state
(defun make-node (state parent value depth)
   (list state parent value depth))

; get the state from a node
(defun get-state (node)
   (car node))

; get the parent state from a node
(defun get-parent (node)
   (cadr node))

; get the value from a node
(defun get-value (node)
   (caddr node))

; get the depth from a node
(defun get-depth (node)
   (cadddr node))

 ;determine if a node represents the goal of a problem
(defun goal-test (problem node)
   (cond ((equal (goal-state problem) (get-state node)) T)
         (T nil)))

; create a list of nodes which represents the states adjacent to the state represented by node
(defun expand (node problem)
   (expand-aux node (cadr (assoc (get-state node) (adj-list problem))) nil ))

; helper function for expand
(defun expand-aux (node states L)
   (cond ((null states) L)
         (T (expand-aux node 
                        (cdr states) 
                        (append L (list (make-node (caar states)
                                        (get-state node)
                                        (+ (get-value node) (cadar states))
                                        (+ (get-depth node) 1) )))))))

; recover the solution path from the final (goal) node and the list of expanded nodes
(defun solution (node nodes)
   (solution-aux node nodes nil))

; helper function for solution
(defun solution-aux (node nodes L &aux temp)
   (setq temp (parent node nodes))
   (cond ((equal temp nil) (cons (get-state node)  L))
         (T (solution-aux temp nodes (cons (get-state node) L)))))

; find the parent node of a node in a list of nodes
(defun parent (node nodes)
   (assoc (get-parent node) nodes))

; determine if a node's state is already the state of a node in nodes
(defun already-present (node nodes)
   (cond ((assoc (get-state node) nodes) T)
         (T nil)))

;;;;; Breadth-first Search ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(defun breadth (problem)
   (breadth-aux problem                                              ; the problem
                (list (make-node (initial-state problem) nil 0 0))   ; the fringe list
                nil))                                                ; the closed list

(defun breadth-aux (problem fringe closed)
   (cond ((null fringe)                          ; no place else to look, so fail
              'Failure)

     ((goal-test problem (car fringe))       ; we have reach the goal, so return solution
              (solution (car fringe) closed))

     ((already-present (car fringe) closed)  ; this state was already reached, so go
              (breadth-aux problem               ; on without processing it
                           (cdr fringe)
                           closed))

     (T                                      ; process this node and go on
              (breadth-aux problem
                           (append (cdr fringe) (expand (car fringe) problem))
                           (cons (car fringe) closed)))))

;;;;;;; Uniform-cost Search ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(defun uniform-cost (problem)
  (uniform-aux problem
               (list (make-node (initial-state problem) nil 0 0))
               nil))

(defun uniform-aux (problem fringe closed)
  (cond ((null fringe) 'Failure)

        ((goal-test problem (car fringe))
         (solution (car fringe) closed))

        ((already-present (car fringe) closed)
         (uniform-aux problem (cdr fringe) closed))

        (T (uniform-aux problem
                        (append (cdr fringe) (expand 
                                              (car fringe) 
                                              problem))
                           (cons (car fringe) closed)))))
```

Comment: Missing open parenthesis at the beginning. Also using `setq` to make globals without `declare` gives implementation dependent behavior. Use `defparameter` or `defvar` instead. Also you need to explain what's not working with it and what you have tried.

Comment: The bottom part, uniform-cost, is the exact same as breadth-first.  I need to modify it in order so that it performs a uniform search thus outputting.. (ARAD SIBIU RIMNICU-VILCEA PITESTI BUCHAREST), but I am not sure how to implement it in the right way. I was wondering if someone could explain it or walk me through it as I am very new to Lisp and internet tutorials can only teach you so much.

Comment: If this is more of a search-technique question than a Lisp-programming question, it may be helpful to consider this:  breadth-first-search is an *instance* of uniform-cost search where the cost is just the distance from the root (as number of edges).  That is, if all the edge weights are the same, then breadth-first search and uniform-cost search are the same.  It might be easier to write each search individually and see then how to refactor them into instances of the same parameterized function.